What is the Hilbert scheme of subvarieties of $\mathbb{CP}^n$?
This question was originally posted on mathoverflow but it looks like it might be better suited for here. I'll edit the question slightly.
I am looking to get a more concrete understanding of the Hilbert scheme of projective subvarieties, specifically over $\mathbb{C}$, and to obtain good references on this subject. As my familiarity with algebraic geometry is restricted to only that over the field of complex numbers, I got lost with the formalism of schemes and functors of points presented in the more general accounts I've read online. References accessible to a differential geometer would be most helpful.
I am in particular hoping to understand the corollary of the theorem reproved in this paper:
COROLLARY: There are only a finite number of components in the Hilbert scheme parametrizing smooth surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$ not of general type.
I had originally interpreted this result to mean that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of smooth surfaces not of general type that can embed in $\mathbb{CP}^4$. This is apparently incorrect, or at least this result does not imply that. Now I want to understand the basics of Hilbert schemes over $\mathbb{C}$.
What does a component of the Hilbert scheme actually parametrize? Can it be seen as a moduli space? What do its points correspond to?
Furthermore, what does the above corollary actually imply? Why do we want to know that there are only finitely many such components? What's the motivation?

Why would you NOT want to know that a moduli space has only finitely many components? I am not sure what kind of an answer you wish for.

The Hilbert scheme of Hilbert polynomial 3t+1 has two components, the 12 dimensional one of twisted cubic curves and the 15 dimensional one of plane cubics and a point. Hilbert polynomials are constant in flat families and you can degenerate in a flat family to something quite degenerate like that given by the lex order generic initial ideal say a triple line with embedded point. This is relevant because your case also is codim 2. See the section on motivation in this pdf.

@CraniumClamp Knowing that there are finitely many components of a moduli space is only useful if one knows what the components actually parametrize. Besides, I still don't know whether this Hilbert scheme IS a moduli space, let alone what it parametrizes or means at all.

I’m not going to write up a full answer on the Hilbert scheme but it is a moduli space. It parametrizes closed subschemes of the ambient space with fixed invariants.

@Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks for the reference. Do you mean to say that the Hilbert scheme with Hilbert polynomial $3t+1$ has two irreducible components? I believe Hartshorne proved, over projective spaces, that each component of its Hilbert scheme corresponding to a Hilbert polynomial is connected

Yes, the components intersect, in plane curves with a point sticking out into space. Remember these can be non-reduced.

Se also Ravi Vakil's Murpy's Law paper

A picture from that paper.


What does a component of the Hilbert scheme actually parametrize?

$\DeclareMathOperator{Hilb}{Hilb}$If you fix a polynomial $P(t) \in \mathbb Q[t]$, then there is a component $\Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$ of the Hilbert scheme, which parametrizes closed subschemes of $\mathbb P^n$ with Hilbert polynomial $P(t)$. Conversely, every component of the Hilbert scheme is of that form.

What do its points correspond to?

The points of $\Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$ correspond to closed subschemes $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ with Hilbert polynomial $P(t)$. In the following, I will denote such a point by $[X] = [X \subset \mathbb P^n] \in \Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$.

Can it be seen as a moduli space?

Yes, it is a fine moduli space. This means that there is a subscheme $\mathcal F \subset \Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n) \times \mathbb P^n$, flat over $\Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$, such that for each point $[X] \in \Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$, the fiber $\mathcal F_{[X]} = \operatorname{pr}_1^{-1}([X]) \subset \mathbb P^n$ over $[X]$ is exactly $X$. The family $\mathcal F$ is also called the universal family, because for every scheme $S$, and every $S$-flat family of subschemes $\mathcal E \subset S \times \mathbb P^n$, there is a uniquely determined morphism $\varphi_{\mathcal E}: S \to \Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$, such that $$\mathcal E = \varphi_{\mathcal E}^* \mathcal F.$$
This means a point $s \in S$ gets mapped to $[X] \in \Hilb^P(\mathbb P^n)$, if and only if $\mathcal E_s = X$.

Thank you for the explanation. To see if I have begun to understand, the corollary I quoted implies that, given $\text{Hilb} (\mathbb{P}^n)$ the disjoint union of all $\text{Hilb}^P (\mathbb{P}^n)$, only finitely many of its components (that is, only finitely many such polynomials $P$) contain points corresponding to a smooth surface not of general type? Am I to understand that ALL points in such a component correspond to (not necessarily isomorphic) smooth surfaces not of general type?

@PaulCusson I think your first observation is correct. But note that the points correspond to subschemes. Those need not be smooth, nor do they have to be irreducible or reduced. In many interesting cases (maybe even all? not sure!) there is an open subset of a component, which parametrizes smooth subvarieties.

So the only takeaway I can be sure about is that, among the components of the full Hilbert scheme, only finitely many of them contain points that correspond to smooth surfaces not of general type, right? And not all points in such a component are smooth, so in particular one component "contains" many different isomorphism classes of subschemes? I guess I still need to find a way to make sense of "how many" subschemes correspond to a given Hilbert polynomial, if I want a clearer answer to "how many" smooth surfaces not of general type can embed in $\mathbb{CP}^4$.

Anyway I'd be happy to accept your answer if you can also give a bit of insight about the corollary I quoted
